# Laravel 4.2 generate sub query like this

Tags: laravel-4

I want to do like this in Eloquent way.

```
select * from `documents` where (`id` in (select `related_id` from
`common_data` where `meta_key` = 'meta_key_name' and `meta_value` =
'1') or `created_by` = '1')
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
$data = Document::where(function($query){
   $query->whereRaw(" id in (select `related_id` from `common_data` where `meta_key` = 'meta_key_name' and `meta_value` ='1')")
        ->orWhere('created_by',1);
})->get();
```